# How to look into what a package or function is doing in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to read the actual R code for a function that I'm using from a package?

For an example, I'm working with a package called recommenderlab, and I'm interested in learning more about how their "POPULAR" method recommendation works so I can make better business decisions.

Thank you!

EDIT: When I type the function name into the console, I get the following output.

```
standardGeneric for "Recommender" defined from package "recommenderlab"
function (data, ...) 
standardGeneric("Recommender")
<environment: 0x00000000148b8340>
Methods may be defined for arguments: data
Use  showMethods("Recommender")  for currently available ones.
```

Any follow up steps from here?

Comment: Type the function name into the R console

Comment: Run `showMethods` like it says - those are the functions with the code that is run from `Recommender` depending on class. For example, `Recommender.data.frame` is the function used when the first argument of `Recommender` is a data frame.

Comment: This is all explained in the duplicate I linked to. Additionally, the source code for every package is available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/index.html).

Comment: yea, I'm currently reading through the posts you've linked me to. Thank you